# Sticky footer covering content and not sticking to the bottom of the page when scrolling

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I wanted to include a sticky footer on my page that sticks to the bottom of the page, and it does, but if the content of the page is longer and I need to scroll down, the footer stays at the bottom of the visible page, covering the content and if I scroll, the content comes out from under the footer.
I've asked ChatGPT several times, but every time, it has given me a solution that doesn't work for me. I´ll also add it below.

This is the code:
HTML

```html
<footer class="footer">
   hi
</footer>
```

CSS

```css
.footer {
  background-color: #4f2e61;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  color: #f2f2fc;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 5em;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

ChatGPT's code:

HTML

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">
    ...
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    ...
  </footer>
</body>
```

CSS

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't count on ChatGPT anymore, the free version stopped being useful some time ago

Answer (score -1):

For the way you are writing your CSS, it would be easy to just make it a position `absolute`

CSS

```css
.footer {
          background-color: #4f2e61;
          padding: 5px 30px;
          color: #f2f2fc;
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          text-align: left;
          margin-right: 5em;
          left: 0;
          bottom: 0;
    }
```

> If `absolute` don't work, try `relative`

Comment: absolute puts the footer at the top of the page and relative makes the footer stick to the middle of the page.

Comment: does your page have any other content? maybe when you see the footer on the middle of the screen it's just on the bottom of your body. try giving `height: 100vh;` to your body

Comment: nope, it still doesn't work :(

Comment: well, can you post the entire code? I'll do it on my PC

Comment: how do i do that? i literally just made this account 20 minutes ago

Comment: Im sorry, I went to sleep. If you didnt solve yet, there's an edit button under your question